# Insert hash value of a row as new column in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this query in Postgres that returns a hash value for every row of my table:

```
  SELECT
  md5(CAST((f.*)AS text))
  FROM
  my_table f;
```

I want to attach each hash to its corresponding row. How would I take the results for each row and add them to a new column?

Comment: You already have that, so what exactly is your question? Do you want to physically add a new column and UPDATE the table's row with the hash?

Comment: Once you add the hash as a new column, the row will no longer have the same hash.

Comment: @jjanes that's actually ok with me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes you are exactly right, I want to add a new column and UPDATE the table's row with the hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to do.  Whether it is a good idea is a another matter.

```
alter table my_table add hash_col text;
update my_table set hash_col =md5(cast((my_table.*) as text));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Why would you say it is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is yours:

```
Select *, md5(array_to_string(translate(string_to_array(f::text, ',')::text, '()', '')::text[], '')) from my_table as f;
```